# Integrating Context-Sensitive help in WPF application following MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, context-sensitive-help

I am trying to implement Help functionality for my wpf application which is following the MVVM pattern. I have my help file present, which contains many pages according to the application. Now I need to integrate this into my application.

Here are my requirements:

1. Pressing F1 opens a certain page in the help file depending on the view model. For this, I guess, I need to bind the F1 command to my view model. How do we bind keys in views?
2. Pressing F1 on a text field opens help for that text field. I think it will be the same as requirement 1. But the problem here is how will I know that a certain text field, button, or radio button is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Listen for the key in the view (or a base class of the view) and call execute on a HelpCommand on the DataContext.
2. Pass [the control that has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317150/get-focused-control-in-wpf) (or its id, or tag, ...) as an argument to the HelpCommand.

[Alternative way to find the focussed control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835186/get-element-that-stole-focus-before-it-does-in-wpf) by using the FocusManager

Here is an example:

ContextHelp C#:

```
public static class ContextHelp
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeywordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Keyword",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ContextHelp));

    public static void SetKeyword(UIElement target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(KeywordProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetKeyword(UIElement target)
    {
        return (string)target.GetValue(KeywordProperty);
    }
}
```

ViewBase:

```
public abstract class ViewBase : UserControl
{
    public ViewBase()
    {
        this.KeyUp += ViewBase_KeyUp;
        this.GotFocus += ViewBase_GotFocus;
    }

    void ViewBase_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(this, true);
    }

    void ViewBase_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F1)
        {
            var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModelBase;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                var helpTopic = "Index";
                var focusedElement = 
                    FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as FrameworkElement;
                if (focusedElement != null)
                {
                    var keyword = ContextHelp.GetKeyword(focusedElement);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
                    {
                        helpTopic = keyword;
                    }
                }
                viewModel.HelpCommand.Execute(helpTopic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand HelpCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName="")
    {
        var p = PropertyChanged;
        if (p != null)
        {
            p(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

AViewModel:

```
class AViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public AViewModel()
    {
        HelpCommand = new RelayCommand(HelpCommandExecuted, (p)=>true);
    }

    private void HelpCommandExecuted(object parameter)
    {
        var topic = parameter as string;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topic))
        {
            HelpText = String.Format("Information on the interesting topic: {0}.", topic);
        }
    }

    private string _helpText;

    public string HelpText
    {
        get { return _helpText; }
        private set
        {
            if (_helpText != value)
            {
                _helpText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AView C#:

```
public partial class AView : ViewBase
{
    public AView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

AView XAML:

```
<local:ViewBase x:Class="WpfApplication2.AView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding HelpText}" Margin="10,254,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36"/>
        <Button local:ContextHelp.Keyword="Button Info" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox local:ContextHelp.Keyword="TextBox Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="29,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <CheckBox local:ContextHelp.Keyword="CheckBox Info" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox local:ContextHelp.Keyword="ComboBox Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</local:ViewBase>
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="500">
    <Grid x:Name="ViewPlaceholder">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var view = new AView();
        var viewModel = new AViewModel();
        view.DataContext = viewModel;
        ViewPlaceholder.Children.Clear();
        ViewPlaceholder.Children.Add(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a change by creating an attached property to inject the help keyword. So no more hijacking the Tag property. Added the ContextHelp class and changed the ViewBase and AView.Xaml

Comment: I tried your first version. I launch application, press F-1, nothing happens. After that I click on some textbox or listview and the press F-1 help file opens. So ViewBase_KeyUp doesn't fire up when I launch application and don't select any control. What the reason behind this.

Comment: You need a focused View for this to work. So you could set the focus from code when the application loads.